# remove window.onload from javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a banner rotator script with the following codes:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var advertises = document.getElementsByClassName("MainAdverTiseMentDiv");
    var scripTags = document.getElementsByClassName("adScriptClass");
    var scripturl = scripTags[0].getAttribute('src');
    var siteurl = scripturl.replace("/assets/ads/ad.js", "");
    var inx;
    for (inx = 0; inx < advertises.length; inx++) {
      advertises[inx].setAttribute("style", "position:relative; z-index: 0; 
        display: inline - block ");
        var getAdSize = advertises[inx].getAttribute('data-adsize');
        var getPublisher = advertises[inx].getAttribute('data-publisher');
        var AdUrl = siteurl + '/ads/' + getPublisher + '/' + getAdSize;
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhttp.customdata = advertises[inx]; xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            this.customdata.innerHTML = this.responseText;
          }
        }; xhttp.open('GET', AdUrl, true); xhttp.send();
      }
    }

    function hideAdverTiseMent(elem) {
      elem.parentElement.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

but some sites say that they have window.onload = function()

on their site and so my banners will not display.

how can i change the "`window.onload = function()`" to something elese to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

You put your code in an IIFE function:

```
(function(){}
   // do something..
)()
```

So your code will gets executed immedantly. Next step is, whenever somebody bind in your script he should put the `defer` keyword in it like this.

```
<script defer sr="path/to/script"></script>
```

`defer` means, that this scrip will wait till the DOM content is loaded and then it will execute that script.